# Alternative ways to understand time-varying comovement between two time-series?

Tags: time-series, correlation, cointegration, relationship, dependence

I have been looking into ways to better understand how the dependencies/correlations/etc between two time series can vary over time.

I first thought about using a Kalman/particle filter over a linear model to get a time-varying slope estimate. However, I'm worried that this will also pick up changing relative variances between the two time series and an increasing slope estimate doesn't actually mean a stronger relationship between the two time-series.

I have looked into time-varying quantile regression but am unconvinced that a changing slope parameter means much, even if it accounts for asymmetry over the various quantiles. The same thing goes for the new [time-varying cointegration](http://econ.la.psu.edu/~hbierens/TVCOINT.PDF) technology.

I have other reservations about DCC-GARCH because to the best of my knowledge it's a time-varying estimate of the Pearson estimator and is therefore not able to pick up non-linear dependencies (since it's essentially the time-varying square root of the $R^2$ of a linear regression). I'm concerned that the DCC-GARCH correlation estimate might decrease because linear dependencies are reducing, even if non-linear dependencies are increasing.

So what else is there and how can it help me to pick up the time-varying dependencies between two time series that accounts for both linear and non-linear relationships? Something like a time-varying Kendall tau or time-varying mutual information would be nice.

Comment: "time-varying dependence between two time series". Do you mind elaborating what you mean with that? Differencing the time series?

Comment: @Freddy Something that captures both the time-varying linear AND non-linear correlation/relationship between two time-series. I've edited the title to make it less confusing. Also, I have just learned that various 2006+ copula methods have been developed that can achieve what I want.

Comment: thanks, interesting, I admit I lack a bit of knowledge when it comes to copulas. Do you have papers or any reference in that regards?

Comment: @Freddy This one seems to be a good one: http://www.wisostat.uni-koeln.de/Institut/LSMosler/Manner/Manner_Reznikova%282010ER%29.pdf

Comment: @Freddy Apparently it also allows us to look at the time-varying correlation at the distributional extremes, sort of like a time-varying quantile correlation estimator (which actually has just been invented in the last 6 months, including standard error asymptotics, although nobody has referenced it yet). It's applied to good effect here: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1059056010001358

Comment: thanks for the links. I never traded much correlation products, so I am not well versed with copulas.

Comment: Answer to the question is that time-varying Kendall's tau can be estimated through a time-varying copula with something like a GJR-GARCH-ARMA-t for the univariate marginal distributions.

Answer (score 3):

I think you fail to understand Multivariate Garch model such as DCC models since they *do* take into account non linearity. They are interested in jointly modeling the time series behavior of multiple conditional variance processes.

Each *couple* of series has its own particular conditional correlation process evolving trough time in a non-linear way. In fact they are devoted to this understanding of co-movement. I recommend you to have a look to this excellent survey:

> Bauwens, L., Laurent, S., & Rombouts, J. V. K. (2006). Multivariate
>   GARCH models: a survey. Journal of Applied Econometrics, 21(1),
>   79–109. http://doi.org/10.1002/jae.842

ex : the conditional correlation of serie A and B may be modeled as autoregressive process  while each of one having its own different conditional variance process. The conditional correlation of serie A and C is a different autoregressive process. Both processes have square terms allowing no-linear relationship. Also, They  can have explanatory variable and feedback to the conditional mean process (Arch-in- mean models). Don't see them as simple "Pearson estimator" processes.

However another interesting class of models you can have a look are Unobserved Components Models (which can be estimated via state space models). They are recents and you can model the joint behavior of multiple series. A good starting point is the following book :

> An Introduction to State Space Time Series Analysis by Jacques J.F.
>   Commandeur,Siem Jan Koopman (2007).

Finally, you can also have a look to multivariate stochastic volatility models, which you can also estimate with state space models and kalman filter.